# Change textview through a button in a widget

Tags: java, android, arrays, button, widget

I have to create a widget for a project but I'm new to Java and especially to widget.

What I'd like to do is to change a `TextView` when I click on a button and to choose what I'll show in an array.

Something like this sequence :

1. Button clicked.
2. Random number generated.
3. Choose the sentence corresponding in the array.
4. Set it in the `TextView` .

Can you please give me some clues or methods to help me ?

Here is my onUpdate void, I've tried a few thing and it just show the changment I've done in my Sentence() void.

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds[i]);
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewAppWidget.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.new_app_widget);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Ln, pendingIntent);
    Sentence();
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, sentence);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
}
```

Comment: have you tried anything so far or you can go through this doc http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html

Comment: What have you tried so far to create your widget? Please edit the question to show the code you've written. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to improve your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, I advice you do follow some tutorial like
[Button tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-button-example/)
and [java random number generator](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=62)

Here it's how to handle the click on your button

```
    //retrieve your button from your xml
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);

    //handle the click on your button
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Update your array
        }
    });
```

Here is how to generate random number

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem is that findViewById don't work with widget it's only for "regular" activity :/ 

However, thanks for the random part, I'll try to use it :)

Comment: what did u mean by " findViewById doesn't work with widget" ? findViewById() return a generic View so you'll have to make a cast (see my example)

Comment: I mean that it can't be used in a widget, maybe because there is no activity. 

I can't find my button with this method.

Comment: Ohh sorry, i miss understanding your question, inside of your widget your should have a context which can be cast as an activity so you'll have ((Activity) context)..findViewById(R.id.myWidgetId)